# Wrong value in matplotlib yticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot from pandas dataframe and matplotlib show wrong value in yticks

Height data:


`2014-08-08 06:00:00  2609.494
2014-08-08 05:45:00  2609.550
2014-08-08 05:30:00  2609.605
2014-08-08 05:15:00  2609.658
2014-08-08 05:00:00  2609.703
2014-08-08 04:45:00  2609.741
2014-08-08 04:30:00  2609.769
2014-08-08 04:15:00  2609.787
2014-08-08 04:00:00  2609.799
2014-08-08 03:45:00  2609.802`

Code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.Dataframe('mydata')
 df.plot()
```

Link of ploted graph:
http://bayanbox.ir/id/7161086291332750314?view

I don't know have to put value like '2609.703' in yticks instead of what shown in graph

Comment: Also see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2796 and the discussion there in

Answer (score 3):

It's not showing incorrect ticks, it's just displaying things relative to an offset value (notice the text at the top of the y-axis).  By default, this happens whenever you're displaying large number with very little difference between them.

It easiest to control this using [`ax.ticklabel_format(...)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format).  In your case, you want to specify `useOffset=False`.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [2609.494, 2609.55, 2609.605, 2609.658, 2609.703,
        2609.741, 2609.769, 2609.787, 2609.799, 2609.802]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data)

ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if you're using the `plot` method of a Pandas `DataFrame`, its return value is the axes object, so just:

```
ax = df.plot()
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is about setting the Y tick formatter of the plot

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.ticker

data = [
["2014-08-08 06:00:00",  2609.494],
["2014-08-08 05:45:00",  2609.550],
["2014-08-08 05:30:00",  2609.605],
["2014-08-08 05:15:00",  2609.658],
["2014-08-08 05:00:00",  2609.703],
["2014-08-08 04:45:00",  2609.741],
["2014-08-08 04:30:00",  2609.769],
["2014-08-08 04:15:00",  2609.787],
["2014-08-08 04:00:00",  2609.799],
["2014-08-08 03:45:00",  2609.802]]

df = pd.DataFrame([ [ datetime.datetime.strptime(d[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), d[1]] for d in data ])

p = df.plot()
p.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%.1f"))
```

Creates:

[image]

The beef here is on the last two lines, the beginning is just recreating the dataframe. The format string given to the `FormatStrFormatter` is the C style format string (here one decimal).