# Incorrect graph from Pandas plot

Tags: pandas, plot

Can anyone explain why the graph from the pandas plot doesn't display any of the numbers from the dataframe?

```
b = df_trend.ask[:10]
print b
0     100.86
2     100.85
3     100.84
4     100.84
5     100.85
7     100.85
9     100.85
11    100.84
12    100.85
14    100.85
Name: ask, dtype: float64
```

Output of the graph from using the plot method looks like this

```
b.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: what is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some odd reason pandas consider 100.xx as large number?  Setting the offset to False solved the problem.

[Wrong value in matplotlib yticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221377/wrong-value-in-matplotlib-yticks)

Comment: more precisely, matplotlib considers the range of y-values (+/- 0.01) to be small relative to their magnitude (10^2)

Comment: Understood. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

pandas shows everything correctly - you can see it if you specify `ylim` parameter:

```
df.plot(ylim=(100.8, 100.9))
```

if you want to disable scientific notation use:

```
ax = df.plot(ylim=(100.8, 100.9))
ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]